# Can I add a new sprint (Fix Version) in YouTrack using a command?

Tags: youtrack

Like the title says, I need to create a new fix version or sprint from my web app.  I have mostly been using commands via YouTrackSharp to perform the tasks I need to, but I have got a bit stuck with this one. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean adding a completely new value to Fix Versions bundle (set of values), then it's not possible. You can do it only in administration part of your YouTrack.
In case you mean adding another fix version to an issue, just use the command 'add Fix versions '.

Regards,
  Alexander

Comment: That is not true, it is an option on the Agile board. You don’t have to do it through administration, I can just click new sprint on the agile board and a new “fix version” is created.

Comment: how about adding one via the rest api?

Comment: it's possible. PUT /admin/project/{project}/version/{version}. Optional params are description, releaseDate, isReleased flag, isArchived flag.

Comment: Yeah, I am on that. I am extending the YouTrackSharp project on Github to do so.

Comment: @Alex.V It should be PUT `rest/admin/project/{project}/version/{version}` at least since version 5.2.1.